# Flickering while changing the cursor on the mouse move event of custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I have created a custom control.

I have drawn a text inside the control.

In that, I'm trying to change the default cursor to Hand cursor when moving the mouse pointer on a particular region(Region where the text drawn inside the control).

For that, I have changed the cursor on the MouseMove event of the control.

```
if (textRect.Contains(e.Location))
{
     Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

I'm getting a flickering effect when moving the mouse over the control.

That is, the cursor is changed to hand cursor and back to default cursor.

I can't able to figure out why it is happening.

Provide your valuable suggestions to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is because the normal message handling for the control changes the cursor as well, changing it back to Cursors.Default.  You need to set the [this.Cursor property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx) so this doesn't happen.

Comment: @HansPassant My provided code works well for me though. It doesnt appear any *flicker animation* and it looks fluent without stuttering.

Comment: You are missing the point of the question, this is about *some* parts of the control providing a different cursor.  So MouseEnter/Leave is not good enough.